# hide html elements but keep them part of isotope

Tags: jquery-isotope

I have elements(divs) in jquery that have display none. They are still given space in the fitting. I now I can filter them out, but that seems to have other consequences

I guess it would help to state what I am attempting to do. I want to display an alternative div on hover. This works except for the space given to the

```
display: none
```

divs

[image]

on hover

[image]

here is my code if it helps

html

```
 <div id="item-container">
 @for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
 {
     <div class="item">@i</div>
     <div class="secondary">@i test</div>
 }
 </div>
```

css

```
#item-container .item {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: grey;
}

#item-container .item:hover {
  z-index: 0;
}

#item-container .item:hover + .secondary {
  display: block !important;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: -11.2%;
}

#item-container .secondary {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one obvious way to get around this is do a parent div that holds both divs that I want to toggle between

instead of

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

do

```
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

than attach the isotope to the parent container. no need to change style except for the margin portion if you want them to be appear over the other space